# How to set Target Audience in WebPart Programitically?

Tags: web-part, audience-targeting

How to set Target Audience in SharePoint 2013 web part Programitically?

i am trying to do it by following [link](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/11/10/how-to-programmatically-set-the-target-audience-on-a-web-part.aspx).But i gor error of access denied even if i use SpSecurity.RunwithElvetedprivilages..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please share your code in your post :)

Comment: Don't have much idea but may be you could try by using `allowunsafeupdates`.